# Merging a branch of a branch after first branch is squashed when merged to master

Tags: git, squash, arcanist

Here's a workflow that I commonly deal with at work.

```
git checkout -b feature_branch
# Do some development
git add .
git commit
git push origin feature_branch
```

At this point the feature branch is up for review from my colleagues, but I want to keep developing on other features that are dependent on `feature_branch`.  So while `feature_branch` is in review...

```
git checkout feature_branch
git checkout -b dependent_branch
# Do some more development
git add .
git commit
```

Now I make some changes in response to the code review on feature_branch

```
git checkout feature_branch
# Do review fixes
git add .
git commit
git checkout dependent_branch
git merge feature_branch
```

Now this is where we get have problems.  We have a squash policy on master, which means that feature branches that are merged into master have to be squashed into a single commit.

```
git checkout feature_branch
git log # Look for hash at beginning of branch
git rebase -i  first_hash_of_branch # Squash feature_branch into a single commit
git merge master
```

Everything is cool, except with `dependent_branch`. When I try to rebase dependent branch onto master or try and merge master into it, git is confused by the re-written/squashed history and basically marks every single change in `depedendent_branch` as a conflict.  It's a PITA to go through and basically re-do or de-conflicticize all of the changes in `dependent_branch`. Is there some solution to this?  Sometimes, I'll manually create a patch and apply it off a fresh branch of master, but if there's any real conflicts with that, its even worse to fix.

```
git checkout dependent_branch
git diff > ~/Desktop/dependent_branch.diff
git checkout master
git checkout -b new_dependent_branch
patch -p1 < ~/Desktop/dependent_branch.diff
# Pray for a clean apply.
```

Any ideas?  I know this happens because of the re-written history during the squash, but that's a requirement that I can't change.  What's the best solution / workaround?  Is there some magic I can do?  Or is there a faster way to do all the steps involved with manually creating the diff?

Comment: As an aside, `git add .` is completely evil, and will eventually bite you when you wind up committing things you didn't mean to. You should be using `git add -p` or at the very least `git add -u .`

Comment: You should be rebasing dependent_branch onto the feature branch once you've made your code review changes. Then when ready to go to master, rebase feature branch onto master, and squash the commits and then merge feature branch into master.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

A little bit about why this happens:

I'll let `O` be "original master" and `FB` be "new master", after a feature branch has been merged in:

Say `feature_branch` looks like:

```
O - A - B - C
```

`dependent_feature` has a few extra commits on top of that:

```
O - A - B - C - D - E - F
```

You merge your original feature branch into master and squash it down, giving you:

```
O - FB
```

Now, when you try to rebase the dependent branch, git is going to try to figure out the common ancestor between those branches. While it **originally** would have been `C`, if you had not squashed the commits down, git instead finds `O` as the common ancestor. As a result, git is trying to replay `A`, `B`, and `C` which are **already contained** in `FB`, and you're going to get a bunch of conflicts.

For this reason, you can't really rely on a typical rebase command, and you have to be more explicit about it by supplying the `--onto` parameter:

```
git rebase --onto master HEAD~3  # instruct git to replay only the last
                                 # 3 commits, D E and F, onto master.
```

Modify the `HEAD~3` parameter as necessary for your branches, and you shouldn't have to deal with any redundant conflict resolution.

Some alternate syntax, if you don't like specifying ranges and you haven't deleted your original feature branch yet:

```
git rebase --onto master feature_branch dependent_feature

                                 # replay all commits, starting at feature_branch
                                 # exclusive, through dependent_feature inclusive 
                                 # onto master
```

Comment: I was hoping to see how the git tree for master is different when using --onto. Or perhaps some other way to understand a bit more about how --onto is different.

Comment: --onto simply allows you to be *more selective* about which commits you would like to replay onto a branch. By default, git tries to "figure out" which commits should be replayed. When you use --onto, you explicitly instruct git to replay a *certain range of commits*. 

In my example, if you did not use --onto, you would end up with O - FB - A - B - C - D - E - F and numerous merge conflicts since FB and A - B - C contain the same changes. By using --onto and specifying the last 3 commits, you end up with O - FB - D - E - F, as the original asker was looking for.

Comment: To make it a bit easier than trying to count back the number of commits, you can copy the commit hash for C from `git log` output. By using --onto and specifying the commit hash for C, you still end up with O - FB - D - E - F but it will be more clear to other readers how this example follows the documentation you provided in the code comments. :)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case it seems you "know" that **only** the squashed work of the branch you originally worked on has been put into master.

So you can happily merge by keeping your changes every time when there is a conflict. There is an option for that:

`git merge -Xours master`

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase for details more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, that may not be the case.  If there is time between code reviews for feature_branch and dependent_branch, it's possible the feature_branch might be merged and pushed and someone else might add something conflicting before dependent_branch is landed.

Answer (score 0):

I heartily disagree with the "mash every feature development down into a single commit" policy, but it's their call...

I'd keep the branches as-is, and create a mashed up commit just for publication, in a special branch. Being able to follow the development step by step is valuable, even if management doesn't believe in it. Mark the places of squashes by tags in the "real" branches, you could also add between-squash tags with messages pointing back to the real commits.

Comment: I actually like that squashing, but that's because its actually done by arccanist, and all of the development / commits / code review for a feature branch is stored in phabricator...but I see your point for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In case your dependent branch has multiple non-trivial changes, rebasing like @joshtkling suggested, can become painful. I have often turned to an alternative strategy which might be easier. This doesn't mean using rebase is wrong or anything, I just want to offer an alternative. It uses the "ours" strategy, but in contrast to @nha's answer it also works if there is more work on the master.

Suppose the starting situation

```
O - A - B - C (feature_branch) - D - E - F (dependent_branch)
  \
   - D - Cs (squash merged feature branch) - G - H (master)
```

where D, G and H are work done by others, possibly squash merges from other branches not shown here.

Merging dependent_branch into master is likely to produce conflicts, because the changes from A, B and C are duplicated. In order to tell git that it does not need to consider these, we can introduce a new merge base that combines C and Cs, by creating a temporary branch and then merge that into our dependent branch. This way git has much more knowledge for merging.

```
git checkout -b temp Cs
git merge C --strategy ours
git checkout dependent_branch
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

The second merge might yield some conflicts, but in my experience they are fewer and simpler to solve than when using rebase. Afterwards merging dependent_branch and master should be a lot easier.